# java library to maintain database structure

Tags: java, sql, database, structure

My application is always developing, so occasionally - when the version upgrades - some tables need to be created/altered/deleted, some data modified, etc. Generally some sql code needs to be executed.

**Is there a Java library that can be used to keep my database structure up to date** (by analyzing something like "`db structure version`" information and executing custom sql to code to update from one version to another)?

Also it would be great to have some basic actions (like add/remove column) ready to use with minimal configuration, ie name/type and no sql code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [DBDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/). Although I haven't used it in the past, it sounds like this project would help in your case. DBDeploy is a [database refactoring manager that](http://dbdeploy.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/05/taking-control-of-your-database-development.pdf):

> "Automates the process of establishing
>   which database refactorings need to be
>   run against a specific database in
>   order to migrate it to a particular
>   build."

It is known to integrate with both Ant and Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org).

> Liquibase is an open source (Apache
>   2.0 Licensed), database-independent library for tracking, managing and
>   applying database changes. It is built
>   on a simple premise: All database
>   changes are stored in a human readable
>   yet trackable form and checked into
>   source control.
>
> Supported features:
>
> - Extensibility
> - Merging changes from multiple developers
> - Code branches
> - Multiple Databases
> - Managing production data as well as various test datasets
> - Cluster-safe database upgrades
> - Automated updates or generation of SQL scripts that can be approved and
>     applied by a DBA
> - Update rollbacks
> - Database ”diff“s
> - Generating starting change logs from existing databases
> - Generating database change documentation

Answer (score 2):

We use a piece of software called [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) for this. It's very flexible and you can set it up pretty much however you want it. We have it integrated with Maven so our database is always up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) (400 questions tagged on SOW) or [mybatis](http://flywaydb.org/) (1049 questions tagged). To add to the comparison the other options mentioned: [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) (663 questions tagged) and [DBDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/) (24 questions tagged).

Another resource that you can find useful is the [feature comparison](http://flywaydb.org/#features) in the Flyway website (There are other related projects mentioned there).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into OR Mapping libraries, e.g. [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/about/why-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Most ORM mappers have logic to do schema upgrades for you, I have successfully used [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) which gets at least the basic stuff right automatically.

Comment: Have you ever tried to move from ORM to OGM? We're moving from Oracle to Mongo, and I'm wondering if I can just get away with changing the libraries, or if there's documentation to assist with the transition...