# How to handle schema upgrades on production databases in Spring Applications

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

What are your best practices for making an upgrade procedure on a production database using Spring framework and hibernate?

Comment: Some other options: [DBDeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/) and [mybatis](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Migration). Check this [other answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28055489/2658613)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also take a lot at Flyway : http://flywaydb.org

Much simpler than Liquibase.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). It does have support for [Hibernate](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/hibernate)

Comment: Liquibase rocks for this... you beat me to answering this by less than a minute.

Comment: There should be a way to share the glory : )

Answer (score -1):

My method (we ship a product where we might have to upgrade from a version 5,10,15 etc versions old).

- Version your schema and keep a copy of each version alongside the current schema
- On installing store which version you updated to in a database table
- Write a installer process that calculates the upgrade steps to go from current db version -> software latest version
- Provide a method for adding custom upgrade steps for each version to migrate tables from old schema to new schema
- Make all custom upgrade steps rerunnable, as you can't transaction some of this stuff (DDL) changes

Optionally

- Have a dumb schema updater that can update your tables but not the data, ie renaming a column it wouldn't be able to figure out what to do with the old data (lost)
- Using the custom upgrade steps have pre and post dumb-schema-updater steps, the first to migrate important data that the dumb updater would lose/break, the second to fix any data after schema updated.

Comment: @aweigold - Why?  What happens if you have two steps for a version upgrade, first one succeeds and the second fails?  I need to have the first one detect it has nothing to do.

Comment: You should track what changes have been applied, or determine if the change needs to be applied.  (BTW, Liquibase will do that ;-) )  The checks to see if all your changes have been applied can be done just as easily on a per change level than by brute forcing it many times until the checks succeed.  Just hammering the same changes over and over is a hack.

Comment: Fair enough let me restate what I meant by rerunnable.  If the upgrade step runs again having already been applied it should detect it has already made the changes and do nothing.