# How to correctly deploy a Spring+JPA application

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, deployment

I'm very new to Spring and I was wondering how to correctly deploy an application. At the moment, I'm deploying the application on Heroku and it works fine.

My doubt is: locally, I'm working with generateDdl (in JPA/Hibernate) set to true (so that DB tables are generated from Java classes). They told me that this is a bad practice on a production server.

I'm wondering what is the best way to apply architectural DB changes when releasing a new version of a (live) website. I mean, if I work on a testing environment with generateDdl=true and then I want to apply the architectural DB changes to the live environment (which has generateDdl=false), how do I know which architectural DB changes occurred since the last version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977487/320180